# git put all too master, force, no compare

Tags: git

I am on `develop` branch, I have no unstaged chages, I tagged my `develop` branch to `v1.0.1` now I want to put it to `master`.

I would like to put all the changes from `develop` to `master`.

**I don't want to resolve conflicts**, I just want to take the `develop` and put it as is to `master`, like the files from `master` never been there.

Is there a simple way to do such an operation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I had to use GitLab,

- navigate to `branches`,
- move the `default` branch from `master` to `develop`,
- completely remove the `master` branch, then
- create a new `master` branch from `develop`, after that
- re-put the default gitlab branch to `master`...

Answer (score 1):

Move branch (pointer) `master` to `development`:

```
git branch -f master development
git push -f origin master
```

See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--f)

Comment: I want to keep my master as master, my develop as develop, just at the moment remove all from master and put all from develop

Comment: The command removes neither `master` nor `develop`; it moves the pointer to the common commit. From which point you can continue developing the branches separately.

Comment: I tried both answers, the result is the similar. If between the master and the develop there are conflicts, is not possible to escape from merges...

Comment: After the command there will be no difference and no conflicts. Because for a brief period `master` and `develop` will be the same not only in the current code but also in history.

Comment: the problem here is that `origin/master` and `master`, and `origin/develop` and `develop` are not the same, so, the manipulation is on the local master, not on the origin... and after the command I have conflicts between distant and local branches, so I have to pull and push, and when i try it, I have merge conflicts.

Comment: Updated the answer with additional command: `git push -f origin master`

Comment: it does not work just to push, because after the first command I have to pull as well... it creates in master two pulls and a lot of pushes to do.

Comment: when I try to push, it says to pull first, when I try to pull, it says there are conflicts to manage.

Comment: "*…after the first command I have to pull as well…*" No, you need to force-push, not pull. The wrong pull is the source of you problems and conflicts.

Comment: did you mean `-f origin/master`?

Comment: No, `git push -f origin master`; force-push branch `master` to remote `origin`.

Comment: it's true I tried to push, but probably didn't use force... because a regular push didn't work because of the pull it created

Comment: Yes, my bad, I should wrote the second command with the first answer immediately.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with my question I have so many downvotes... anyone didn't had to reset the master from develop?

Comment: now, I can't test this because I already removed my master branch and recreated from the develop... (

Comment: the same push-pull problem I had with the second answer from 0x5453

Comment: Yep, you should force-push, not pull after `git reset --hard`

Comment: however I don't really understand why it created things to pull, if I updated only the local master version

Comment: Exactly because `master` and `origin/master` are diverged, so `pull` tries to merge. Force-push makes `origin/master` the same as `master`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest I can think of:

```
git stash  # if you want to keep any unstaged changes, stash them so they won't be lost in the `reset`
git checkout master
git reset --hard develop
```

Comment: thanks @0x5453 see the comments from the phd's answer